# Org-mode: overwriting globals #+PROPERTIES: in block headers?

Tags: org-mode

It is often the case that I want to have `:results silent` for all the code blocks in an `Org-mode` document. Do simplify my block headers, I define this in my Org-mode document:

`#+PROPERTY: header-args :results silent`

That works properly: all the codeblocks uses the `:results silent` option in the blocks' header.

However, if I specify `:results output` in one of the code block, it will still be `silent`. I would have expected that it would overwrite the global setting, but it doesn't seem so.

Am I right by saying that or is there something I am missing to get this behavior?

Here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :results silent

...

#+BEGIN_SRC clojure
;; this one is silent
(def foo "bar)
#+END_SRC

...

#+BEGIN_SRC clojure :results output
;; this one is being outputted
(def foo "bar)
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Could you please provide a MWE which illustrates what you want to do and the result? This will make helping much easier.

Comment: @Rainer thanks. I just updated with an example. The first code block is silent, but the second one too even if I specified a different value for `:results`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug, present even in the most up-to-date version of org-mode. I've reported it on the org-mode mailing list.

EDIT: Charles Berry pointed out on the ML that this is **not** a bug. The opposite of "silent" is "replace", so the second source block should read:

```
   #+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results output replace
   ;; this one is being outputted
   (princ "foo")
   #+END_SRC
```

See http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/108001/focus=108008
and the :results section in the manual http://orgmode.org/org.html#results

Note that you get to pick one value for every section (collection, type, format, handling) - if you don't pick a value for a section, a default value is picked. In the above, there was no explicit value for "handling", so the default value from the property still controlled.

Comment: BTW, I mdified your source blocks to use elisp rather than clojure. I don't know clojure but it seems to me that your second block does not produce any output, so :results output is likely to be ineffective. You might try just `:results replace` in that case.